# How do I show and interact with Google Maps using a desktop Java application?

Tags: java, google-maps, desktop

I'd like to be able to display **Google Maps** on my screen, and interact with the map to add points, create routes, draw trails, etc.

I would like to avoid opening a webpage to Google Maps - I instead want to be able to program the map directly.

I have a `Google Maps API Key` (I'm not sure which type I need), and I have a vague idea that I need to use the `API` somehow.

As a somewhat inexperienced programmer, I'm feeling a little overwhelmed.  Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this that I can see an easy way and a hard way.

1) Use a WebView in JavaFX to display the google map, something along the lines of.

```
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    webEngine.load("http://wwww.googlemaps.com");
```

2) The other way is to use google api's to serve as the backend of your code base and use JavaFX / Swing to serve as the front end. This would involve a considerable amount of work on your end and the scope of walking you through it is a bit beyond what I am willing to commit to on this forum. You will need to learn a bit on backend services and how to consume them and recreate map elements using your own elements.

Comment: Hi Ira!  Thanks for the information.  Can you elaborate a little bit about the second option?  

The first option looks pretty good right now, but is it possible to use JavaFX instead of JPane?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a bit more information, good luck!

Comment: Thank you!!  These suggestions were really helpful.  Unfortunately, it looks like the first option won't be powerful enough to meet our application's needs.  

Is there any help you could offer on the second route?  We can use all the help we can get :)

Comment: Try this library https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/gmapsfx-add-google-maps-to-your-javafx-application/